# How to add button in javascript row

Tags: javascript

in my application I fetch data from api and view in table. the view data is working fine. now I want to add button for each row where can I add "view" and "edit" button. any idea how can I do it

```js
< script >
  fetch("http://localhost/E-CommerceAPI/AI_API_SERVER/Api/Item/ViewItemAPI.php").then(
    res => {
      res.json().then(
        data => {
          if (data.body.length > 0) {
            var temp = "";
            data.body.forEach((itemData) => {
              temp += "<tr>";
              temp += "<td>" + itemData.ItemCode + "</td>";
              temp += "<td>" + itemData.UserMememberNo + "</td>";
              temp += "<td>" + itemData.Description + "</td>";
              temp += "<td>" + itemData.Description2 + "</td>";
              temp += "<td>" + itemData.ItemGroup + "</td>";
              temp += "<td>" + itemData.ItemType + "</td>";
              temp += "<td>" + itemData.StockControl + "</td>";
              temp += "<td>" + itemData.TaxType + "</td>";
              temp += "<td>" + itemData.ItemBrand + "</td>";
              temp += "<td>" + itemData.ItemModel + "</td>";
              temp += "<td>" + itemData.IsActive + "</td>";
              temp += "<td>" + itemData.CreatedTime + "</td>";
              temp += "<td>" + itemData.ItemCode + "</td></tr>";

            });
            document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = temp;
          }
        }
      )
    }
  ) <
  /script>
```

Comment: So what do the view and edit buttons do?

Comment: both button will pass the ItemCode to another function once user click on that specific button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So add buttons

```
temp += "<td>" + itemData.ItemCode + "</td>";
temp += "<td><button type='button' data-action='edit' data-id='" + itemData.ItemCode + "'</td></tr>";
```

Listen for click event

```
document.getElementById('data').addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
  var elem = evt.target;
  var action = elem.dataset.action;
  var itemCode = elem.dataset.id;
  if (action === "edit") {
    console.log("edit", itemCode);
  }
});
```